# How to embed javascript into a remote loading bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, django, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap

Currently i'm loading a remote URL inside a bootstrap modal dialog, i've recently attempted to load a captcha (the remote URL is a login/register form) into the modal, but it seems the script gets stripped out. is there any way of avoiding/counteracting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap uses [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to inject remotely delivered HTML into the modal. That method removes `<script>` tags before injecting, to prevent errors in IE. [Here's a link to the annotated source](http://robflaherty.github.com/jquery-annotated-source/docs/12-ajax.html#section-32) where it does that.

In general, it's a bad idea to expect HTML received from AJAX as a string to execute its `<script>` tags. If you have control over the remote server, you might want to refactor your approach and load the CAPTCHA script into your document separately.